# Ruby’s secret trick to avoid “class methods” and keep its type system simple and elegant

Tags: ruby

From Wikibooks' [Ruby Programming/Overview](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Overview#Singleton_Classes):

> When I said that every Ruby object has a class, I lied. The truth is, every object has two classes: a “regular” class and a singleton class. An object’s singleton class is a nameless class whose only instance is that object. Every object has its very own singleton class, created automatically along with the object. Singleton classes inherit from their object’s regular class and are initially empty, but you can open them up and add methods to them, which can then be called on the lone object belonging to them. `This is Ruby’s secret trick to avoid “class methods” and keep its type system simple and elegant`

The above passage says that Ruby's secret trick to avoid class methods. I don't understand what the author means here. Where is Ruby stopping us to avoid class methods? for an example, look at the example shown below

```
class Raj
  def self.hi
    puts 'Hi'
  end
  def hello
    puts 'hello'
  end
end

object=Raj.new

object.hello
Raj.hi
```

As you can see in the preceding example, the class methods can still be created.
yes?
I understand that there are no true class methods in Ruby; instead, they are methods that are created for the Raj object.
But, in any case, it's allowing me to create the method 'hi,' right?
So, what does it mean when it says, 'This is Ruby's secret trick for avoiding "class methods" and keeping its type system simple and elegant'?

Comment: Don' t forget that `def self.hi; puts 'Hi'; end` is just shorthand for `singleton_class.define_method(:hi) { puts 'Hi' }`, where `hi` is an instance method defined on `Raj`'s singleton class (`Raj.hi` displays `'hi'`). We could also write `class Class; def hi; puts 'Hi'; end; end`, so  that `Raj.hi` displays `'hi'`, but that has the undesirable effect of making the method `hi` available to all classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I understand that there are no true class methods in Ruby; instead, they are methods that are created for the Raj object.

That's exactly it, though.

```
def self.hi
  puts 'Hi'
end
```

This is *not* a class method or static method. Those don't exist in Ruby. That's the whole point. Your class `Raj` defines an *object* of type [`Class`](https://ruby-doc.org/3.2.0/Class.html). We can see its type with the `#class` function.

```
> Raj.class
 => Class
```

We can also see its ancestors.

```
> Raj.class.ancestors
 => [Class, Module, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

`Class` inherits from `Module`, since (for the most part) classes can do everything modules can. `Module`, in turn, inherits from `Object`, which has some modules of its own mixed in (`PP:ObjectMixin` is for pretty-printing, and `Kernel` gets you the nice helpers like `puts`) and eventually inherits from the root class `BasicObject`.

But this isn't the whole story, for `Raj` has its own class as well: its *singleton class*. We can see the full story by calling `#singleton_class` instead of `#class`.

```
> Raj.singleton_class.ancestors
 => 
[#<Class:Raj>,                                                                  
 #<Class:Object>,                                                               
 #<Class:BasicObject>,                                                          
 Class,                                                                         
 Module,                                                                        
 Object,                                                                        
 PP::ObjectMixin,                                                               
 Kernel,                                                                        
 BasicObject]
```

Now there's a lot more going on. `Raj` is an instance of the singleton class of `Raj`, which inherits from the singleton class of `Object`, which in turn inherits from the singleton class of `BasicObject`, which inherits from `Class` and all of the stuff we saw before.

So when you define a method on the class `Raj`, you're defining it (as an instance method) on the singleton class `#<Class:Raj>`. And that class (currently) has one instance: `Raj`.

---

By the way, it's also useful to know that the term "singleton class" is a bit of a lie. As you can see, the class is very much not a singleton in general. For instance, the singleton class of `Object`, called `#<Class:Object>` above, actually has several instances: `Object`, `Raj`, `String`, and most Ruby classes. Personally, I prefer to call them [eigenclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/eigenclass/info) for that reason, but "singleton class" is the official (and more well-known) term.

Comment: _"the singleton class of `Object` [...] has several instances"_ – not really. The string `"abc"` is an object, but it's not an instance of `Object`: `"abc".kind_of?(Object) #=> true` but `"abc".instance_of?(Object) #=> false`. Likewise, `Raj.kind_of?(Object.singleton_class) #=> true` but `Raj.instance_of?(Object.singleton_class) #=> false`. A singleton class has only 1 direct instance.

Answer (score 3):

The author is talking about the singleton class in this sentence, there is a really nice article to deep dive into ruby singleton class: https://medium.com/@leo_hetsch/demystifying-singleton-classes-in-ruby-caf3fa4c9d91

Here is a nice example extracted from this article:

```rb
class Vehicle
  def initialize(kms)
    @kms = kms
  end
  def drive
    puts "let's go!"
  end
end
  
car = Vehicle.new(1000)  
bus = Vehicle.new(3000)

def car.drive  
  print "I'm driving a car! "
  super
end

car.drive # "I'm driving a car! let's go!"  
bus.drive # "let's go!"
```

As you can see, here the `#drive` method has been overridden but only for the `car` object, the `bus` object is still using the `#drive` method defined in the `Vehicle` class.

This new method is defined on the singleton class (or shadow class) of the object, this is allowing you to define new methods on the fly on an object without polluting all the objects of this class.

Answer (score 3):

This means that Ruby doesn't implement class methods.

Indeed, the Ruby OBJECT Model, allows you to "emulate" the definition of class methods by defining instance methods on the Eigenclass:

```
class Greeting
  def self.hello
    'hello world!'
  end

  def self.eigenclass
    class << self
      self
    end
  end
end

Greeting.eigenclass      # => #<Class:Greeting>
Greeting.eigenclass.name # => nil

Greeting.singleton_methods                  # => [:hello, :eigenclass]
Greeting.eigenclass.instance_methods(false) # => [:hello, :eigenclass]
```

First, we define a `Greeting.eigenclass` method. This method returns `self` in the context of the eigenclass — by using the `class << self ... end` syntax. In this case, `self` contains an unnamed instance of the class `Class` (a.k.a an anonymous class). This anonymous class keeps track of the class to which it is attached — the `Greeting` class in our case.

Then, we can see that the singleton methods of the `Greeting` class are the instance methods of the `Greeting` eigenclass.

Feel free to have a look to this [very detailed article](https://medium.com/rubycademy/understanding-the-eigenclass-in-less-than-5-minutes-dcb8ca223eb4) to learn more about this concept.

Answer (score 2):

To illustrate @Sébastien P.'s answer:

```
dice = [1,2,3,4,5,6]  #an ordinary array instance

def dice.throw        #now it has an extra
  sample
end

p dice.throw #=>3
```